# changing google maps marker position

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to update marker position by text field value (adress)
And I got functions

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var mapa;
var marker;

function initialize() {

if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {


 mapa = new GMap2(document.getElementById("mapa"));
mapa.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
mapa.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
mapa.addControl(new GOverviewMapControl(new GSize(140,110)));
var center = new GLatLng({/literal}{if $mapa.lat ne "" && $mapa.lat ne "a"}{$mapa.lat}{else}51.919438{/if}, {if $mapa.lng ne "" && $mapa.lng ne "a"}{$mapa.lng}{else}19.145136{/if});
mapa.setCenter(center, {if $mapa.zoom ne "" && $mapa.zoom ne "a"}{$mapa.zoom}{else}6{/if}{literal});

marker = new GMarker(center, { draggable: true});

GEvent.addListener(marker, "dragstart", function() {
mapa.closeInfoWindow();
});

GEvent.addListener(marker, "dragend", function() {
document.getElementById('lat').value = marker.getPoint().lat();
document.getElementById('lng').value = marker.getPoint().lng();
document.getElementById('zoom').value = mapa.getZoom();
});

mapa.addOverlay(marker);

}

}
function getLocation() {
   var geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
    address = document.getElementById("location").value;
     geocoder.getLatLng(
    address,
    function(point) {
      if (!point) {
        alert(address + " nie znaleziony");
      } else {
        alert(point);
        mapa.setCenter(point, 13);
        marker.setMap(mapa);
        marker.setPosition(point);
       // mapa.addOverlay(marker);

      }
    }
  );


}
</script>
```

I don't know why marker isn't moved, even isn't added another one. One is staying on first position, but map is changing on type address

Comment: this doesn't look like the google maps API v3, are you using a wrapper to convert v2 API to v3 or you just mistyped the tag?

Comment: It's inside smarty, what wrapper?

Comment: gmaps API v3 doesn't have those global G* constructs anymore. All objects are inside the google.maps.* namespace. for example `GMarker` becomes `google.maps.Marker`. That's why I asked if you are using the incorrect tag on your question.